# Where does a clustered index store row data for keys on intermediate levels?

Tags: sql-server, rdbms

Please help me in understanding what I feel is inconsistency between two facts:

1. SQL Server stores data in a B-Tree structure
2. Only leaf nodes contain actual table data, while intermediate ones store only keys and pointers to children

In general, a B-Tree has the property that, for a given key in the intermediate node, all keys in the left subtree are smaller than it and in the right subtree greater, such that:

[image: Example B-Tree]

In the above example ([image credit](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:B-tree.svg)), clearly a row with the ID = 7 was inserted into the table. But where is the row data (non-key columns) for that ID if it can't be in the root node of the example and there is no 7 in the leaf nodes?

Clearly, there's more to it than "indexes are B-Trees" and I would appreciate some insight.

Comment: I don't know what the answer is but thanks for posting something interesting. perhaps reference the Wikipedia page directly in the post, with a link rather than just stating the image source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That diagram is for a B-tree, but technically speaking SQL Server uses a B+tree structure.  Scroll down a bit in that [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) and you will find

> In the B+ tree, copies of the keys are stored in the internal nodes; the keys and records are stored in leaves; in addition, a leaf node may include a pointer to the next leaf node to speed sequential access (Comer 1979, p. 129).

Thus the internal nodes would only have a *copy* of the keys, and will be duplicated in the leaves (where, in the case of a clustered index, the actual data are held as well).

You can find more specifics [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177443(v=sql.105).aspx).  You'll notice in the comments section a couple other folks noting that SQL Server uses a B+tree.

Answer (score 3):

I think good overview is this article:

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-storage-internals-101/

See part Indexes. There is shown, that nodes as 7 or 16 has also their leafs
Also, I highly recommend book:

SQL Server 2012 Internals by Kalen Delaney

[https://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Server-Internals-Developer-Reference/dp/0735658560](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735658560)

Answer (score 2):

When building a B-Tree index, it starts with the leaf level - the data is sorted and written to data pages and a double-linked list created.

The smallest key value (NULL from the very first page) is taken from each page and used to build the index pages for the next level of index, so each row in the index page contains the ID of the page below and the smallest key value from it. It does the same again, taking the smallest key value from each index page, to create the next level.

This continues until everything fits into a single page - this is the root.

Pages on all intermediate levels and the root follow the same patters, page ID and the smallest key value from that page.

In the picture above, assuming it's just the three leaf level pages and the root, the root should contain `(pageID:1 Key:NULL)`, `(pageID:2 Key:9)` and `(pageID:3 Key:18)`.

Answer (score 1):

*(Please excuse my Word drawing skills)*

Although your image does represent a B-Tree, the actual SQL Server has a slightly different implementation, specifically a B+Tree. I'll try to explain using visuals as well, taking the below diagram as an example:

[image]

As the diagram shows, the keys do not exist only in one node (in this case the root), but they are copied and distributed to the children nodes up until the leaf nodes. (In this case the tree only has 2 levels, root and leaf-levels).

So, when running a query for the key `(Adams, Joe)`, the key will be looked for in the B-Tree as per the rules you mentioned in the question (smaller keys to the left, greater keys to the right).

This will continue until a **LEAF** node is reached.

At this point there are 2 distinctions, specifically for SQL Server:

- non-clustered index (represented in the diagram above):

  - contains a ROW_ID / PAGE_ID column which points to a data page where that row exists
  - the database engine retrieves that page and looks inside it for the ROW_ID
- clustered index:

  - contains the entire data page at the leaf level
  - the database does not need to retrieve the page because it is already at the leaf level, and just does a lookup for the key inside the page